# Ethereum upgrades to 1.8.20 sync data, data compression causes synchronous data to stop

Tags: go-ethereum

The following situation occurs in the log during the Ethereum synchronization process.

```
 INFO [12-24|14:14:24.470] Imported new chain segment               blocks=39 txs=5439  mgas=265.638 elapsed=8.072s    mgasps=32.905 number=5094982 hash=f4584c…a81f3a age=10mo1w4d  cache=0.00B
 INFO [12-24|14:14:32.712] Imported new chain segment               blocks=40 txs=6200  mgas=304.909 elapsed=8.242s    mgasps=36.994 number=5095022 hash=dff296…d2db97 age=10mo1w4d  cache=0.00B
 WARN [12-24|14:14:41.858] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:15:42.133] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:16:42.197] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:17:42.788] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:18:43.037] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:19:43.461] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:20:43.906] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:21:44.201] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:22:44.668] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
 WARN [12-24|14:23:45.280] Database compacting, degraded performance database=/data/eth_data/geth/chaindata
```

1. Geth version

   ```
    Geth/v1.8.20-stable-24d727b6/linux-amd64/go1.11.2
   ```
2. The 1.7.x version did not happen like this
3. If this happens, continuing to synchronize for a while after reboot will still result in data compression.
4. A similar problem on github also seems to be unresolved, seeing someone replying to version 1.8.11 after about 3.5 days of compression, starting normal synchronization
5. I hope to get help, thanks to everyone who responded